# How to design algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-design, combinatorial-design

I am a newbie to algorithm designing. I am working on user association and load balancing algorithm designing in millimeter wave wireless communications.

In this topic I am able to formulate the problem, but my query is how does one decide the algorithm after completing problem formulation.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You start with simple algorithms, implement them successfully, and then you learn how to do more and more complex things. You need experience, and some built-in cleverness. Without both you will fail.

This is like asking a baker "how do you come up with new cake recipes" or an inventor "how do you invent new things".